# Trying to create PHP CRUD app using PDO but getting Undefined type 'App\PDO' in config file

Tags: php, pdo

Entire project - https://github.com/steve-davey/phpsqliteconnect (config file is out of date though)

This is the config file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Config {
   /**
    * path to the sqlite file
    */
    const PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE = 'db/DeviceAssetRegister.db';

}

/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'DeviceAssetRegister');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I don't understand why I get an error for `PDO` whereas I don't for the index.php file in the directory above?

`$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:./db/DeviceAssetRegister.db');`

That works absolutely fine! I even get a little pop-up description in VSC that links to the PHP documentation. So why does it throw an error in the other file please?? TIA!

Comment: You MUST NOT write any other code in the same file that contains a class definition

Comment: It would be good to know why? In any case, the only reason why it is like that is because I've been using these two tutorials, and they both have a config.php file, so the code is a combination from both https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php (PDO version of code) + https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-php/connect/ Perhaps I should put the code within the class instead?

Comment: Because you wouldn't have encountered this error at all?

Comment: I don't understand. I thought the solution was either importing `PDO` or using `new \PDO`, as mentioned below. I opted for the latter and that appeared to solve the problem. I still don't know what else you think I'm supposed to do as regards the class definition, by the way. I don't seem to be able to put the `try/catch` block within the class.

Comment: you don't need any try/catch blocks here in the first place.

Comment: Well, there's something else I don't understand  I was just trying to see if I could move that whole block into the `SQLiteConnection` class. I thought that might make more sense since that's what it's doing and I appear two have two block of code in two different files trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO` is a class from the root namespace. Unless you use that root namespace properly (by either importing `PDO` or using `new \PDO`), PHP will search that class from the current namespace (which is `App`)

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. Thanks ever so much. I will need to do a bit of reading to understand that properly but I get the idea. Thanks again!

Comment: It would be good to know how to import `PDO` though. Would it be like `Class Config extends PDO`?

Comment: Why not check the basics of PHP? `use PDO` is how to import it. `extends PDO` makes no sense, unless you try to implement an extension to the base class

Comment: OK, well I didn't know that, that's why I asked. Thanks.